# -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to fetch the data from two arrays and get data from third array taking that index . Everything worked fine until second iteration . tagsIdarray and tagsArray has 3 arrays each and each array has their respective count (Basically it is array of arrays ). pretagarray has its respective count.

```
 if(tagsArray!=(id)[NSNull null])
         {
             for(int i=0;i<[tagsArray count];i++)
             {
                 for(int j=0;j<[[tagIdsArray objectAtIndex:i] count];j++){
                     if([[tagIdsArray objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:j]==[preTagArray objectAtIndex:j])
                     {
                         selectedTagCompleteArray = [[tagsArray objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:j];
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
```

> Example tagsArray objectAtIndex:i count = 4,5,20
>   tagsIdsArray objectAtIndex:i count = 4,10,8
>   pretagArryCount = 15

Comment: Does tagIdsArray and tagsArray have same count ? If not your code will crash.

Comment: Looks like a very complicated data structure.

Comment: You still didn't answer my question. what is the count of tagIdsArray ?

Comment: I've written my arraycounts below the count . Please Check it

Comment: In your questiuon you said " tagsIdarray and tagsArray has 3 arrays and each array has their respective count " but you mentioned array count as 1 for tagsArray. Please take your time andupdate the question with valid details.

Comment: It is array of arrays so I meant to tell that tagsIdarray and tagsArray has 3arrays each in which there are different arrays

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for ?

```
if(tagsArray!=(id)[NSNull null])
{
    for(int i=0;i<[tagsArray count];i++)
    {
        NSArray *tagsArrayElement = [tagIdsArray objectAtIndex:i];

        for(int j=0;j<[tagsArrayElement count];j++){
            id tagElement = [tagsArrayElement objectAtIndex:j];

            for(int k=0;k<[preTagArray count];k++){
                id preTagElement = [preTagArray objectAtIndex:k];

                if(tagElement==preTagElement)
                {
                    selectedTagCompleteArray = tagElement;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish with your code. The error you are getting is because you are trying to access an index on `NSArray` that does not exist. It's hard to provide an implementation without understanding exactly what results you would like to achieve, however a way to avoid the crash is to check the counts of `NSArray`s *before* you use `objectAtIndex:`. Something like this:

```
if ([tagsIdsArray count] == [preTagArray count]) {
     //the arrays match and you can safely iterate
}
else {
     //the array sizes do not match and will crash if you iterate
}
```

If the `NSArray` counts are not equal, then it likely doesn't make sense to iterate over them to perform an operation. I would think through why the arrays do not match. Clearly one of your arrays only has 2 values as it appears to make it through index 0 and 1. You can try to `NSLog()` the array counts for every array (or log the `objectAtIndex:`) in your loops and this will likely turn up the culprit.